# How to get value in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying get a value inside a JavaScript array from the output of an AJAX request.

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax-test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "sku=800270",
    dataType: "html"

    }).done(function(resposta) {

        console.log(resposta);
}
```

Ajax-Test.php:

```
$produto[] = array('sku'    => $product->getSku(),
                   'name'   => $product->getName());

var_dump($produto[0]);
```

Returns:

```
array(6) {
  ["sku"]=>
  string(6) "000188"
  ["name"]=>
  string(80) "Cuba Gastronômica Aço Inoxidável para Buffet GN 1/2×65mm (325x265mm) - 812-2"
}
```

I need to access the values inside the array, something like:

```
var sku = resposta["sku"]
```

In my tests if I try to print `resposta["sku"]` its giving me "undefined variable".

Comment: Change `dataType: "html"` to `dataType: "json"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On php side you need to change `var_dump($produto[0]);` to `echo json_encode($produto[0])`. On JS side you need to change your request to `dataType: "json"`, because it is not a html response. Then you can access the fields by the property names.

```
var sku  = resposta.sku;
var name = resposta.name;
```

Your aproach is not wrong to, to access by a string:

```
var sku  = resposta["sku"];
var name = resposta["name"];
```

So for conclusion, your php:

```
$produto[] = array(
    'sku'    => $product->getSku(),
    'name'   => $product->getName()
);

echo json_encode($produto[0]);
```

Your AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax-test.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: "sku=800270",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(resposta) {
    var sku  = resposta.sku;
    var name = resposta.name;

    console.log(sku, name);
}
```

Comment: It wouldn't be `$produto[0]`, though, would it? **Edit:** Oh, yes, I see, it would be. Probably make more sense just to drop the `[]`: `$produto = array('sku'    => $product->getSku(), 'name'   => $product->getName()); echo(json_encode($produto));`

Comment: This belongs to what he want to to. Because he uses `$produto[]` to assign another array, `$produto[0]` isn't wrong here. It would work. But if he want to have more products there, he have to use `echo json_encode($produto);` and do more actions on JS side ... but that belongs to the usecase. @T.J.Crowder

Answer (score 1):

- Set a proper `dataType` for ajax object as `dataType: "json"`
- Change your `Ajax-Test.php` file content as shown below(to send a proper `json` responce):

  ```
  $produto[] = ['sku' => $product->getSku(), 'name' => $product->getName()];       
  echo json_encode($produto[0]);
  ```